Name of a horror movie about ghosts that come back to haunt a town
I watched this movie a lot when I was a child but can't remember the name.
The female protagonist has an ill mother who dies, suffocated with cooking gas, one night when the protagonist was out in a date, so she decides to move to another town.
At this new town she meets a guy and kinda starts a relationship with him. Also there's a girl in the neighbourhood who always comes to visit her and sometimes the girl suddenly appears at her attic.
The woman learns the girl of the attic is the ghost of the dead twin sister of the other girl that visits her. The twins names are Flora and Fauna and that's the only names I can remember.
She also finds out the town was built into other town that was submerged and many people died because of it and kind of cursed the town. In an accident some years ago a number of people died and their ghosts back to haunt town time to time and her new boyfriend is one of them.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year? Was is Americam?

@rory: Are you still around?

Flora and Fauna were the names of twins in the Addams Family (1991).

Ghost Lake (2004)


In a small town in upstate New York, local residents were drowned as a dam was built and the town was flooded to create the Rushford Lake. One hundred years later, the souls of the drowned are becoming restless...

A girl named Flora, or Saundra, is in the film, and one of the reviews mentions the mother dying from cooking gas while the protagonist is out on a date.
